# css not applying on div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to apply css to my div (questionFrame) I'm woundering why it is not working? See snippet. Could someone help?

```css
#questionFrame {
  border: 5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="questionFrame">
  <span style="color:#0091ea"><p id="date">Date Created</p></span>
  <div id="userQuestions"></div>
  <center>
    <div class="grid-container4">
      <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn #00e676 green accent-3" style="width:50%" onclick="grabData()">Proceed</a>
      <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn #ef5350 red lighten-1 " style="width:50%">Cancel</a>
    </div>
  </center>
</div>
```

Comment: This should work, css selector is correct. Maybe other css code overwrites your css.

Comment: a simple documentation look up of the `border` property and you get it ...

Comment: first rule of SO is search and research - it would have taken you a lot longer to type this question out than to type "border css" into a search engine

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border even has a special highlighted note: **The border will be invisible if its style is not defined. This is because the style defaults to none.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have not specified the [border style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-style) (for example "solid"). You can either do these separately:

```
#questionFrame {
  border: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color: black;
}
```

Or in a single statement:

```
#questionFrame {
  border: 5px solid black;
}
```

I would recommend that latter.

Comment: Oh thank you you for the explanation :) it works now

Answer (score 2):

```css
#questionFrame{
  border: 5px solid black;
}
```

```html
   <div id="questionFrame" >
   <span style="color:#0091ea"><p id="date">Date Created</p></span>
   <div id="userQuestions"></div>
   <center><div class="grid-container4">
  <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn #00e676 green accent-3" style="width:50%" onclick="grabData()">Proceed</a>
  <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn #ef5350 red lighten-1 " style="width:50%">Cancel</a>
  </div></center>
   </div>
```

OR as your code:

```
border: solid;// not 5px
border-width: 5px;
border-color: black;
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't set any style for your border like `border:5px solid;` or `border-style:solid;`

Here you can read more about the border styles: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
#questionFrame{
border:5px solid #000;
}
```

Or You can style like this

```
border: solid;
border-width: 5px;
border-color: black;
```

Answer (score -3):

Did you link it. Use

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="YourStylesheet.css">
```

In the head of your html